# Radio button required attribute is not working

Tags: html

I’m working on a web page using HTML. The scenario is:

```
<section>
    <form>

        <!-- FIRST DIVISION -->
        <div> 
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" >
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- SECOND DIVISION -->
        <div>
            <form>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- THIRD DIVISION -->
        <div>
            <form>
            </form>
        </div>

     <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
</section>
```

From the above scenario, a section has a form which in turn has few divisions in it. My question is: how can I put a single submit button (as shown above) at the bottom after the third division which collects all the entered data from the user and submits it?

The problem I faced trying this is with the radio button's `required` attribute. When I submit the form, it is not prompting me that It is a required field. How do I make changes to my code so that the radio button prompts me that it is a required field?

Comment: Why do you have nested forms?

Comment: It's working for me. Are you using Safari?

Comment: Chrome @Pyromonk

Answer (score 1):

try removing the other form tags and also the `required` in radio button like below.

```
<section>
    <form>

        <!-- FIRST DIVISION -->
        <div> 

                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" >

        </div>

        <!-- SECOND DIVISION -->
        <div>

        </div>

        <!-- THIRD DIVISION -->
        <div>

        </div>

     <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
</section>
```